# How to implement SSO between a Angular based apllication using OIDC(Open Id Connect) and a application built on .net using SAML

Tags: angular, single-sign-on, openid-connect, saml-2.0, okta

I have build an application using Angular and have used Okta OIDC for authentication. Now i have to integrate it with a .net based application using Okta SAML2.0 to achieve single sign on i.e. There is a landing page, and there are 2 sets of user one is the internal one and other is external one. The landing page is a application build on .net and is using SAML2.0 for authentication. Angular application will be placed as icon on the landing page and if the user clicks the icon, the user should be able to access the application.

How to achieve this requirement?

Comment: Why not switch your .NET app to use OIDC? That's probably the easiest way to make this work.

Comment: Other than what @MattRaible said, I think there is SAML assertion flow for OIDC - https://developer.okta.com/docs/concepts/oauth-openid/#saml-2-0-assertion-flow